# Accessing SPNEGO authenticated web service from Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, kerberos, spnego

I am trying to access a REST service that uses Kerberos authentication (company internal) from a Python app on Windows. However, it seems that the service is configured to expect a SPNEGO only as when I try to use requests-kerberos to connect as in:

```
requests.get('servicename', auth=HTTPKerberosAuth())
```

it produces a 500 Error from the server with:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: GSSException: No credential found for: 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
```

My guess is that server is configured to expect SPNEGO only and Python client supports only Kerberos.

I have tried installing PyKerberos but that fails as it expects krb5 on the system and I am doing this under Windows. Are there any libraries available that could help me do a SPNEGO call from Python in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else would be having a similar problem - resolved by using pycurl with pycurl.HTTPAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE attribute set.

Comment: Don't use the `HTTPAUTH_GSSNEGOTIATE`. It has been [deprecated](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/37f0e8a32cf9ad0a87f8c60cfa12b65e61be15a9/docs/libcurl/symbols-in-versions#L20) last year in favor of `HTTPAUTH_NEGOTIATE`.

Comment: This doesn't solve the python issue - just works around it by using curl.